# When is it not a good idea to lure out clan castle troops?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just entered TH 10. I've been seeing many bases (some war) where the clan castle is not in the middle and to the side or corner.

In the past, I would always lure out CC troops to destroy them first. But should this be done even if you can 2 star the base without triggering the CC troops?

My goal when attacking is to get 2 stars (unless it's war, even then I'd rather ensure 2 stars than lure out the cc troops to increase chance of 3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luring clan castle troops out is generally a good idea, as they can sometimes wreck havoc on your troops, however it is not always necessary. For example, if you know what troops are in the clan castle (if someone already attacked the base during war) and they won't disrupt your troops, you can sometimes safely ignore them. To illustrate, if they have all Valkyries or other troops that cannot attack air troops and you are attacking with all air troops, it isn't worth taking the time to kill the troops that won't be able to attack yours.

Some troop compositions are also better at dealing with clan troops without taking significant damage. For example a GoValWi (golems, valkyries, wizards) attack will generally be able to deal with any ground based clan troops, as the valkyries will kill the clan troops quickly with their high aoe damage.

You can also do modified queen walks in which you use a queen and some healers to clear out a portion of the base and pull the clan troops, as a high level queen and a few max healers can deal with pretty much any clan troops, especially if you have a rage spell for them.

Answer (score 3):

Under th8 it is good idea to lure troops out. But later th luring troops is difficult where can be easily triggered by hogs but just seem to as a waste of precious time. So at this time most war bases are large and you will blame why you've wasted your time luring troops out, where you can just kill them on the go between attack. So it's just about personal preference whether to lure or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, almost all of the time I see a base with the clan castle off to the side, there are no troops in it. I think a lot of people do this if they're in an inactive clan that doesn't donate much, and they want to use their core real estate for storages or whatever.

So when I see the CC on the outskirts, I generally just ignore it, or drop a cheap barbarian or archer next to it just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attacking with all dragons you don't need to lure clan castle troops out just take out air defences. If you are attacking with ground troops You should lure the clan castle troops otherwise you may lose the attack especially if there is a dragon or balloons.